# Sending Given Inputs to Database by using MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter

I am designing an application by using MongoDB and Tkinter. I am trying to take inputs from user and send them to the database.
Here is my code

```
def inputFunc():
    inputWindow = Tk()
    inputWindow.title("Müşteri Ekleme Ekranı")
    inputWindow.geometry("500x500")
    
    submitButton = Button(
        inputWindow,
        text = "Müşteriyi Ekle",
        width = 30,
        height = 5,
        fg = "DarkOrange1",
        bg = "green3",
        command = addClientFunc)
    submitButton.place(x=150,y=350)
    
    c_id = Label(inputWindow, text = "Müşteri Numarası").place(x = 30,y = 50)
    c_name = Label(inputWindow, text = "Müşteri Adı").place(x = 30,y = 70)  
    c_firmName = Label(inputWindow, text = "Firma Adı").place(x = 30,y = 90)
    address = Label(inputWindow, text = "Adres").place(x = 30,y = 110)
    engine = Label(inputWindow, text = "Motor Markası").place(x = 30,y = 130)
    power = Label(inputWindow, text = "Motor Gücü").place(x = 30,y = 150)
    phoneNumber = Label(inputWindow, text = "Telefon Numarası").place(x = 30,y = 170)
    email = Label(inputWindow, text = "E-mail").place(x = 30, y = 190) 
    workHour = Label(inputWindow, text = "Çalışma Saati").place(x = 30,y = 210)
    
    idEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 50)
    nameEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 70)
    firmNameEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 90)
    addressEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 110)
    engineEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 130)
    powerEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 150)
    phoneNumberEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 170)
    emailEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 190)
    workHourEntry = Entry(inputWindow).place(x = 180, y = 210)
    
def addClientFunc():
    ins_table_Clients.insert_one({
        "c_id": idEntry.get(),
        "c_name": nameEntry.get(),
        "c_firmName": firmNameEntry.get(),
        "address": addressEntry.get(),
        "engine": engineEntry.get(),
        "power": powerEntry.get(),
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumberEntry.get(),
        "email": emailEntry.get(),
        "workHour": workHourEntry.get()
    })
```

I am getting an error which says idEntry is not defined. First I thought that is about making idEntry global but that didn't work. What can I do to fix that? Appreciated for your helps.

Comment: `idEntry` is a local variable, so will only be visible inside of `inputFunc`. `addClientFunc` isn't inside `inputFunc`.

Comment: Also all entries are assigned the result of `place()` which is always `None`.  So even they are changed to global variables, it still does not work.

Comment: What can I do to fix that? Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. all `Entry` widgets are local variables inside `inputFunc()` which cannot be accessed inside `addClientFunc()`.  You can move `addClientFunc()` into `inputFunc()` as a nested function.
2. all the entry variables are assigned the result of `place()`, so they are all `None`.  You need to separate the line like `idEntry = Entry(...).place(...)` into two lines: `idEntry = Entry(...)` and `idEntry.place(...)`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
def inputFunc():
    def addClientFunc():
        ins_table_Clients.insert_one({
            "c_id": idEntry.get(),
            "c_name": nameEntry.get(),
            "c_firmName": firmNameEntry.get(),
            "address": addressEntry.get(),
            "engine": engineEntry.get(),
            "power": powerEntry.get(),
            "phoneNumber": phoneNumberEntry.get(),
            "email": emailEntry.get(),
            "workHour": workHourEntry.get()
        })  

    inputWindow = Tk()
    inputWindow.title("Müşteri Ekleme Ekranı")
    inputWindow.geometry("500x500")
    
    submitButton = Button(
        inputWindow,
        text = "Müşteriyi Ekle",
        width = 30,
        height = 5,
        fg = "DarkOrange1",
        bg = "green3",
        command = addClientFunc)
    submitButton.place(x=150,y=350)
    
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Müşteri Numarası").place(x = 30,y = 50)
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Müşteri Adı").place(x = 30,y = 70)  
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Firma Adı").place(x = 30,y = 90)
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Adres").place(x = 30,y = 110)
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Motor Markası").place(x = 30,y = 130)
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Motor Gücü").place(x = 30,y = 150)
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Telefon Numarası").place(x = 30,y = 170)
    Label(inputWindow, text = "E-mail").place(x = 30, y = 190) 
    Label(inputWindow, text = "Çalışma Saati").place(x = 30,y = 210)
    
    idEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    idEntry.place(x = 180, y = 50)
    nameEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    nameEntry.place(x = 180, y = 70)
    firmNameEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    firmNameEntry.place(x = 180, y = 90)
    addressEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    addressEntry.place(x = 180, y = 110)
    engineEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    engineEntry.place(x = 180, y = 130)
    powerEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    powerEntry.place(x = 180, y = 150)
    phoneNumberEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    phoneNumberEntry.place(x = 180, y = 170)
    emailEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    emailEntry.place(x = 180, y = 190)
    workHourEntry = Entry(inputWindow)
    workHourEntry.place(x = 180, y = 210)

    inputWindow.mainloop()
```